# ImageResizer custom urls for bundled effects

Tags: imageresizer, custom-url

We're looking to do something with ImageResizer that should be very easy but couldn't find any documentation on it.

We'd like to bundle effects into a shorter url request. 
For example, instead of doing something like guid.jpg?maxwidth=100&maxheight=100&mode=crop&anchor=middlecenter&rotate=90 we'd like to just request guid_thumb.jpg or guid.jpg?bundlemode=1.  Then we'd translate bundlemode into the desired effects.

That way, if we want to add other effects to the bundle, we can just modify the "bundle code".

Please advise.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### These are called *Presets* and are provided by the [Presets plugin.](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/presets)